# Roll up summary with Contact specific

Tags: roll-up-summary

I have a custom object Test__c with a formula field "Marks__c" and master detail relationship on Contact. I need to create a field on Contact which should give me sum of 'Marks__c field but should be contact specific i.e it should add the marks of not all the contacts but should add the marks of Contacts separately and display them on that particular Contact. How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A roll-up summary field on a Master record will always only contain values from its own Detail records. You don't need to do anything special to achieve this.

The [documentation on roll-up summaries](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US) makes this clear.

> You can create roll-up summary fields that automatically display a
>   value on a master record based on the values of records in a detail
>   record. These detail records must be directly related to the master
>   through a master-detail relationship.